# SoapUI global proxy testings not taken for test execution

Tags: proxy, web, soapui, testcase

I have created a web test project using the SoapUi GUI (free version). I need a proxy to connect to the Internet. Therefore, I have set the proxy host and port in File->Preferences->Proxy Settings and made sure that it is enabled. I know the proxy settings are correct, because I see the "soapUi Starter Page" properly. But to my surprise, these global proxy settings do not seem to be taken when running the web test case (I just configured a HTTP GET for http://www.google.com), and my request always times out.

I have failed to make it work both with version 4.0.1 and with 4.05 beta 1.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try with http://stackoverflow.com?

It seems soapui doesn't handle redirect right.

Comment: oh, you are right. It worked perfectly with stackoverflow.com. So it is not really a proxy issue but a redirect one. Thx